# Java 8: How to perform timeout for SSLSocket.startHandshake()

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, java-8, handshake

We have below thread to perform SSLHandshake but in some edge cases I noticed `((SSLSocket) clientSocket).startHandshake();` is blocked forever and its not going to the next block of `while` loop code where SSL_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT is `1500` milli seconds and it works fine, Am wondering if adding `clientSocket.setSoTimeout(90000);` would fix this issue or should it handled in a different way?

**MainServerHandshakeThread**

```
public class MainServerHandshakeThread implements com.ssltunnel.utilities.threading.Shutdown, Runnable {
    private final Socket clientSocket;
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainServerHandshakeThread.class.getName());
    private boolean done;

    public MainServerHandshakeThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;        
    }

    private void handshake() throws CertificateExpiredException, InterruptedException, IOException {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ((SSLSocket) clientSocket).setNeedClientAuth(true);
        MainServerHandshakeHandler handshake = new MainServerHandshakeHandler();
        ((SSLSocket) clientSocket).addHandshakeCompletedListener(handshake);
        ((SSLSocket) clientSocket).startHandshake();


        while (!handshake.isDone() && !done) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            if (duration>SSL_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT) {
                done = true;
                LOG.warn("Handshake timeout");
            }
        }
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();        
        serialNumber = handshake.getSerialNumber();
        LOG.info("MainServer Handshake Handshake done in ms: " + ((stop - start))+" For serialNumber "+serialNumber );        

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            handshake();
        } catch (CertificateExpiredException ex) {
            LOG.error("Client Certificate Expired", ex.getMessage());
            SocketUtils.closeQuietly(clientSocket);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOG.error("Interrupted waiting for handshake", ex);
            SocketUtils.closeQuietly(clientSocket);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.error("IO Error waiting for handshake", ex);
            SocketUtils.closeQuietly(clientSocket);
        }
        finally {
            LOG.debug("Handshake thread is done");
            done = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        if (clientSocket!=null) {
            SocketUtils.closeQuietly(clientSocket);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to [the documentation for `SSLSocket.startHandshake()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#startHandshake--): _This method is synchronous for the initial handshake on a connection and returns when the negotiated handshake is complete._

Comment: It would be better not to perform the initial handshake explicitly at all, let it be done automatically, and set a read timeout on the socket. NB 'Non-blocking timeout' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how can I do the handshake automatically? can you please post it as answer?

Comment: You don't 'do the handshake automatically'. You 'let it be done automatically', as I said. That's what 'automatic' means.

Comment: @user207421 Am quite new to socket world and I don't really understand what you meant by  'let it be done automatically', I really appreciate if you can post it as answer

Comment: @RanPaul: he means "just don't call `startHandshake()` at all". It will be *called automatically* by the JVM when you first try to *read* from or *write* to the socket. That plus a timeout (as you suggested) and it should be fine.

Comment: Btw, did you try what you suggested? Setting `setSoTimeout()`?

Comment: You might want to check [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57190490/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-ssl-serversocket-on-the-same-port), especially the comments might give you some insights.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments (mostly from @user207421): yes, setting a socket timeout through [`socket.setSoTimeout(timeout)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) will be enough to trigger a `SocketTimeoutException` (a subclass of `IOException`) if the handshake process doesn't complete after "some time" (but *not necessarily* the specified timeout<sup>1</sup>).

That is simply explained because `setSoTimeout()` works at the socket level, below the SSL handshake: the handshake protocol performed by [`startHandshake()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#startHandshake--) involves several reads/writes from the socket `Input`/`OutputStream`, which will trigger the timeout itself. In other words: it is not a "handshake timeout" per se, but the "read timeout" on all read operations performed by the handshake itself.

Also, note that you don't need to call `startHandshake()` yourself: the JVM will do that automatically when you first try to read or write from your `SSLSocket` (which is something you usually do early anyway after you get such a socket from an `SSLServerSocket` anyway).

---

<sup>1</sup>: The timeout specified by `setSoTimeout(timeout)` is for a *single* [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--). So the handshake process can timeout (in the worst case) after the number of `read()` it performs, times the `timeout` value you specified.

Comment: Thanks for the response, since we cache the socket connections at server side we can not defer the `handshake` and rely on JVM to do the handshake automatically, We have to performa the handshake manually

Comment: @RanPaul no problem, it's a facility to ease genericity: when you get a `Socket`, you might in fact get an `SSLSocket` (which is a subclass), so you don't need to worry about SSL specifics when reading/writing. There's nothing wrong with calling `startHandshake()` manually, it's just not mandatory. You can still call `setSoTimeout()` and get the handshake process to timeout.

Answer (score -2):

Most implementations of SSLSocket support **setHandshakeTimeout()** but it is not part of the class definition.
I suggest you to look for example at Android code. This is a good example of how to deal with it:
[ssl socket factory wrapper](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/134e092c9b71d8145ba8c7540bac0c392630218f/emailcommon/src/com/android/emailcommon/utility/SSLSocketFactoryWrapper.java#L246) and [ssl socket factory](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/134e092c9b71d8145ba8c7540bac0c392630218f/emailcommon/src/com/android/emailcommon/utility/SSLSocketFactory.java#L283)

Check how they try to set a handshake timeout if exist:

```
    private void setHandshakeTimeout(SSLSocket sslSocket, int timeout) {

    try {

        // Most implementations of SSLSocket support setHandshakeTimeout(), but it is not

        // actually part of the class definition. We will attempt to set it using reflection.

        // If the particular implementation of SSLSocket we are using does not support this

        // function, then we will just have to use the default handshake timeout.

        sslSocket.getClass().getMethod("setHandshakeTimeout", int.class).invoke(sslSocket,

                timeout);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        LogUtils.w(LogUtils.TAG, e, "unable to set handshake timeout");

    }

}
```

And look at how they get a connection:

```
    SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket)

        ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());



    if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {



        // we need to bind explicitly

        if (localPort < 0)

            localPort = 0; // indicates "any"



        InetSocketAddress isa =

            new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);

        sslsock.bind(isa);

    }



    int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);

    int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);



    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress;

    if (nameResolver != null) {

        remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(nameResolver.resolve(host), port);

    } else {

        remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);

    }



    sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);



    sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);

    try {

        hostnameVerifier.verify(host, sslsock);

        // verifyHostName() didn't blowup - good!

    } catch (IOException iox) {

        // close the socket before re-throwing the exception

        try { sslsock.close(); } catch (Exception x) { /*ignore*/ }

        throw iox;

    }



    return sslsock;
```

Hope it helps.